# Android passing different type of arguments to same method

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean

It may sound stupid and impossible.

I would like to call a method with different types of argument. For example, in Android `sendTextMessage` method needs to be called with type of arguments like `sentTextMessage(String, String, String, pendingIndent, pendingIndent)` but I would like to use arguments as `sentTextMessage(String, String, String, pendingIndent, pendingIndent, String, int)`. It sounds impossible... right? I believe if it could be possible by modifying the framework and change the generic class of `sendTextMessage`. But I would like to call the method with both types of arguments by using if statement in a same app.

It seems silly, but I found an app apk that was built in such a way. (I looked it in by dex2jar.)

I tried to force eclipse to build with the argument error by changing build settings but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to supply two more aguments? What do they do?

Comment: In the case of senttextmessage, it may send an altered text message to a service provider. That is what i know.